# How does a javascript onclick attribute work for more output from array with loop?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

// My problem is when my checkit() function is called it only shows the check.png image once next to the first item in array.

```
<?php
require 'connectit.php';

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id")) {
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {

        echo "<h3>He's got $count bills to pay.</h3>";
        echo "<p>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<div id=\"check\" onClick=\"checkit();\"><img id=\"img\" src=\"\" /></div>";
            $id = $row->id;

            echo  $row->bill_name, ': $', $row->bill_cost,
            ' ',"<a href=\"delete_id.php?id=" . $id . "\">X</a><br/><br/>"; 
            echo "</p>";    
        }       
    }
}
?>
//javascript onclick function
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkit(){
document.getElementById("img").src = "check.png";
//needed to put a line through the text, to mark through it but can't figure that out either. I tried this.
document.getElementById("p").style.texttransform = "underline"; //didn't work for me.
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    list[i].src = "check.png";
}
```

***obs***: I haven't tested it.

**update:**

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if(list[i].id == 'some_id') {
        list[i].src = "check.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that checks all of them at once is there a way to make them check individual? Wish I could toggle it on and off with javascript.

Comment: @DrewPeer you can also check if the `id` of the List Index is equals to your `<img> id` you want to change. check my update.

Comment: problem is they all have the same Id they still all get checked. I wish I could send you the file. It is live too. andrewmpeer@gmail.com if you're interested what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

All the "id" attribute in HTML must be unique.

In a way to be more efficient, document.getElementById() stops at the first element with the id you're looking for.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks